# how do I turn a function into a class and pass the form to a Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

in my Django project i have a function:

```
def retail_product_detail(request, slug):
    context = {
        'product_retail': get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug),
        'cart_product_form': CartAddProductRetailForm(),
        'related_products': Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        }
    return render(request, 'retail/single_product_retail.html', context)
```

how can i turn it into class RetailProductDetail and pass the form to be displayed?

i tried:

```
class RetailProductDetail(FormView):

    template_name = 'retail/single_product_retail.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_retail'
    form_class = CartAddProductRetailForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product_retail'] = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['related_products_1'] = Product.objects.select_related('tag').all()
        return context
```

But form doesn't works.

In template:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart_add_retail' slug=product_retail.slug %}" method="post">
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-dark flex-shrink-0" type="submit" value="Add to cart>
</form>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does not work? Does it throw an error or just does not display what you expect?

Comment: the form is not rendered in the template.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you still want to use `FormView`? I'm not very familiar with `FormView`, but I am with just plain `View` and other types of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way:

Instead of:

```
form_class = CartAddProductRetailForm
```

I used:

```
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context['cart_product_form'] = CartAddProductRetailForm
```

Answer (score 1):

its because default context name for form is `form` in FormView CBV
try in template
`{{ form }}`